# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake' in MWAA Airflow Version 2.2.2

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mwaa

I am using Python **snowflake.connector** library to connect to snowflake from MWAA Airflow.
The code is working fine in Airflow version 2.0.2.
Now I am upgrading MWAA Airflow version to 2.2.2 and trying to execute the same code to connect to snowflake. I created new Airflow environment with version 2.2.2.
My requirements.txt file is as shown below:

```
apache-airflow==2.2.2
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.3.0
snowflake-connector-python==2.7.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4
pandas==1.4.3
```

But I am getting error with Snowflake module on Airflow UI as shown below:

```
  **File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/shared/modules/connect_to_snowflake.py", line 11, in <module>
    import snowflake.connector as sf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'**
```

Also, I am not able to view any AWS cloudwatch logs.
I did not find any details about snowflake changes from Airflow version 2.0.2 to 2.2.2.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

**Note**: Below is my requirements.txt file for MWAA Airflow version 2.0.2.:

```
apache-airflow==2.0.2
snowflake-connector-python
```

Comment: Hey Rohit? In your new environment, what kinda result do you get when you run `airflow info` in the console? Especially the "Paths Info" we need to check.

Comment: Just to update, my issue is resolved. Problem was with the requirements.txt file. In Airflow MWAA 2.2,we need to add --contraint "《path of github containing constaints file》" at the start of requirements.txt file. This was weird change i noticed but it worked